# Problem reinterpreting parameters in OpenCL 1.0

Tags: opencl

Is it possible to reinterpret parameters that have been passed into an OpenCL Kernel. For example, if I have an array of integers being passes in, but I want to interpret the integer at index 16 as a float (don't ask why!) then I would have thought this would work.

```
__kernel void Test(__global float* im, __constant int* constArray)
{
  float x = *( (__constant float*) &constArray[16] );
  im[0] = x;
}
```

However, I get a CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE error when I next try to use the command queue, implying that the above code has performed an illegal operation.

Any suggests what is wrong with the above, and/or how to achieve the reinterpretation?

I have now tried:

```
__kernel void Test(__global float* im, __constant int* constArray)
{
  float x = as_float(0x3f800000);
  im[0] = x;
}
```

and this does indeed give a 1.0f in im[0]. However,

```
__kernel void Test(__global float* im, __constant int* constArray)
{
  float x = as_float(constArray[16]);
  im[0] = x;
}
```

always results in zero in im[0] regardless of what is in constArray[16].

Regards,

Mark.

Comment: Hopefully you are actually defining x as a float in those last two cases?

Comment: oops. Sorry, yes!. Ill edit the question to reflect this. Many thanks for taking the time to help

Answer (score 1):

OpenCL includes the [`as_typen`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/as_typen.html) family of operators for reinterpret casting of values from one type to another. If I am understanding the question, you should be able to do something like

```
__kernel void Test(__global float* im, __constant int* constArray)
{
  float x = as_float(constArray[16]);
  im[0] = x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have tried as_float and although this does not result in an invalid command queue, the result is always zero. There seems to be something strange about changing the type of data that is passed into a kernel. It does not seem to depend on whether the data is __constant or __global.

Comment: Which toolkit, OS and hardware are using?

Comment: Ubuntu 64 bit, NVidia Quadro 6000, NVidia driver 270.41.19